# Ruby float to_r calculation. decimals to fractions

Tags: ruby, internals

Can someone clarify why ruby returns such big numbers when using to_r

for example:

```
a = 0.025
a.to_r
3602879701896397/144115188075855872.
```

Why not use 1/40?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a typical floating point problem, but hidden inside. While 0.025 may be represented exactly, the function `to_r` will no doubt perform various floating-point operations internally which are necessarily inexact. The result `3602879701896397/144115188075855872` will no doubt match the intermediate, transformed version of `a` more closely than your proposal `1/40`.

Now `3602879701896397/144115188075855872` is extremely close to being the same as `1/40`. But it is not quite equal, so is not simplified.

For more information, look at [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055618/ruby-floating-point-errors) of the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039650/ruby-bigdecimal-sanity-check-floating-point-newb) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451015/arithmetic-in-ruby) related to inexact floating point. This is a nuanced case and a good question therefore, but has its fundamentals in the same things. I'm looking into the ruby `C` implementation of `Float#to_r` for more details.

Comment: Hmm... `"0.025".to_r #=> (1/40)`.

Comment: To further @steenslag: (in Ruby 2.1.5) `(2/5.0).to_r #=> (3602879701896397/9007199254740992)` yet `(2/5.0).to_s.to_r #=> (2/5)`.  Seems the string implementation of to_r is more accurate than the float implementation?