# Why does 99.99 / 100 = 0.9998999999999999

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, rounding-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dealing with accuracy problems in floating-point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590822/dealing-with-accuracy-problems-in-floating-point-numbers)

Whereas 99.99 * 0.01 = 0.99

Clearly this is the age old floating point rounding issue, however the rounding error in this case seems quite large to me; what I mean is I might have expected a result of 0.99990000001 or some similar 'close' result.

And for the record I got the same answer in a JavaVM and in a .Net environment.

Comment: This has been asked many times before, here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590822/dealing-with-accuracy-problems-in-floating-point-numbers - is just one example

Comment: difference between this answer and 0.99990000001 is the same. you realised this, right?

Comment: And it *is* close as you expected.

Answer (score 5):

Why 0.9998999999999999 is not close enough for you (and 0.9999000000000001 is good )?
abs(0.9999 - 0.9998999999999999) == abs (0.9999 - 0.9999000000000001)

Comment: Ahh yes, 0.999*8*
Well spotted.

Answer (score 2):

It is a floating point error. For (a lot) more detail see this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). Use a `decimal` if you need accurate fractional results (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#Decimal_computation)).

Comment: Or, more precisely, use a `decimal` if you are doing calculations where the **decimal representation** of the result is important.

Comment: Daniel is right:  decimal representation isn't much more accurate than binary.  It does however match the arithmetic we usually use, so when exact matches to existing processes are necessary (like in a lot of financial work), use decimal.