# Dividing a double with integer

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I am facing an issue while dividing a `double` with an `int`. Code snippet is :

```
  double db = 10;
  int fac = 100;
  double res = db / fac;
```

The value of res is `0.10000000000000001` instead of `0.10`.

Does anyone know what is the reason for this? I am using cc to compile the code.

Comment: Duplicate of MANY questions.  See "floating-accuracy" tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does 99.99 / 100 = 0.9998999999999999](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930314/why-does-99-99-100-0-9998999999999999)

Answer (score 10):

You need to read the classic paper [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 4):

The CPU uses binary representation of numbers.
Your result cannot be represented exactly in binary.
0.1 in binary is 0.00011001100110011...
CPU truncates it at a certain point and gets some rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

double is a floating point operator, they do not provide precise values. Look up Precision and Floating Point Operators on google.