# PHP Subtraction Returning Infinite Number

Tags: php, numbers, subtraction

I have an array that store data. If I subtract two arrays I get an infinately big number. Here is an example

```
$i[1] = 2.14;
$i[2] = 2.15;
$diff = $i[1] - $i[2];
echo $diff;
```

The output of this code should be `-1` but instead I am getting `-0.0099999999999998`? With the code I am making I need the numbers to be exact. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? 

Thank you

Comment: ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with accuracy problems in floating-point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590822/dealing-with-accuracy-problems-in-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: @mario that doesn't really help solve the problem for PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of inaccuracies introduced in floating point operations.

For arbitrary precision operations see [BCMath in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).