# irb float implementation

Tags: ruby, floating-point, irb

Just asking this out of curiosity.

I was using **irb** terminal and was trying to  subtract float from float.

I found

```
irb(main):003:0> 49.4 - 0.1
```

gives me

```
=> 49.3
```

but if I do

```
irb(main):003:0> 49.3 - 0.1
```

then I get

```
=> 49.199999999999996
```

Is this something related to the implementation if **irb** ? I mean why 49.3 - 0.1 gives such representation. (This is specific to 49.3 - 0.1, I never got this any other time)

I use **irb 0.9.6**

Comment: Look up the definition of "floating point number" and do some searching around. This is a common question. Floating point numbers are, by definition, not precise.

Comment: try it in C, u will be get the same result.

Comment: Is there *any* question which comes up more often than this... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with accuracy problems in floating-point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590822/dealing-with-accuracy-problems-in-floating-point-numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). This is nothing Ruby or IRB specific.

Comment: I do not think it is useful to refer novices to Goldberg’s excellent article. As its title says, it is for computer scientists. Is there a primer that would be a better introduction for people encountering floating-point issues for the first time?

Comment: I generally start from the assumption that people who are interested will be able to understand this article if they put in the necessary effort.

Comment: Well, I just blew up the entire concept of floating point. My bad. :(