# visual studio 2010 showing weird behavior on float/double increment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, floating-point, floating-accuracy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dealing with accuracy problems in floating-point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590822/dealing-with-accuracy-problems-in-floating-point-numbers)

I am writing an OpenGl animation and am using a float variable "time" to keep track of the time.
I am incrementing the "time" variable by 0.01 .I have certain conditions to fulfil whenever "time" reaches an integer value.The issue is that after a certain time the float increment shows weird behavior.
I start from time = 0 and I see that after "time" reaches 0.83 the next value is 0.839999.
I though this could be related to float precision so I tried using double/long double and I found that instead of reaching the value 1.00 the code is reaching the value 1.0000007.

I tried incrementing by "0.01f" instead of "0.01" but got no success.
Is this some bug in Visual Studio or am I doing it the wrong way?
I could post the code but I don't think it's of much use as I am assigning to "time" just at one place and it's just being used at other places.

Comment: It's not a bug in the compiler.  In fact, whenever you're looking at some odd behavior in your program and the thought occurs to you, "I wonder if this is a bug in the compiler,"  you can rest assured that the answer is never (as near to never as it doesnt matter) "yes"  Accpeting this will make you a happier and more productive programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't ever compare floating point values for equality unless you know *exactly* what you are doing. I would strongly suggest you use integers (perhaps integer numbers of milliseconds) for this purpose.

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more information.

Floating point is a fixed-precision format. This is an inherent limitation of fixed-precision formats.

For example, say you used six decimal digits of precision. One-third would be `.333333`. But if you add one-third three times, you get `.999999`, not 1. That's the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly recommending this, but the issue is that the 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as double. 1.0 can be. So if you make your time-step a (negative) power of two, you will find a difference. By way of illustration:

```
    double delta = 1.0 / 8;
    int stopper = 10;
    int nextInt = 1;
    for (double t = 0; t <= stopper; t += delta)
    {
        if (t == nextInt)
        {
            std::cout << "int ";
            ++nextInt;
        }
        else 
            std::cout << "    ";
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just round "time" after each increment to make sure it maintains a sensible value.

Something like that:

```
double round(double value, double precision)
{
    return floor(value / precision + 0.5) * precision;
}
time = round(time + 0.1, 0.1);
```