# c++ if condition check of double values gives unexpected output

Tags: c++, if-statement, double, precision

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  double a = 0.01;
  double b = 45.01 - 45;
  double c = b;

  if (a == c)
    cout << "a is 0.01" << '\n';
  else
    cout << "a is not 0.01" << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Running the above code gives the output  **"a is not 0.01"** instead of **"a is 0.01"**. I'm not getting why if-statement is messing up the double values of a and c? Here why and a is not equal to b and c?  What should I do to get the desired output of **"a is 0.01"**?

Comment: In general, floating point arithmetic is not exact because of rounding errors, `a` is not equal to `c` but it is **almost** equal to `c`.

Comment: Wait until you add up a large number of doubles. You "should" sort them first to make sure you get a more accurate result otherwise you can loose "more" precision. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a floating point arithmetic problem.

Running this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  double a = 0.01;
  double b = 45.01 - 45;
  double c = b;
  std::cout << a-c << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Will give this output:

```
1.98973e-015
```

This is because of the way floating points are represented in C++.

One thing you can do is to round the result by using the round() function (c++11 or newer compiler) or by casting the result to an integer with few modifications.

I prefer the casting option because in certain cases using the round() function will need a bit more modification if the result is negative.

```
  double d = int( (a - c) * 100) / 100;
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
```

Will give the following output:

```
  0
```

Therefore, this will do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  double a = 0.01;
  double b = 45.01 - 45;
  double c = b;

  double d = int( (a - c) * 100) / 100;

  if (!d) // equivalent to (d == 0)
    std::cout << "a is 0.01" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "a is not 0.01" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

You can read the followings to get a better understanding of the issue -

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

[Comparing Floating Point Numbers, 2012 Edition](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/)

You can also go over the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590822/dealing-with-accuracy-problems-in-floating-point-numbers) from which I have gotten the recommended articles.

Edit:
As Artyer pointed out, this is a way of rounding up the value.
If you use this method you need to replace the '100' int:

```
double d = int( (a - c) * 100) / 100;
```

with `10^x`, where `x` will be the decimal precision you want to have.

Comment: `int((a - c) * 100) / 100 == 0` is a really round about way of saying `std::abs(a - c) < 0.01`, which is the de facto way to check for "close enoughness"

Comment: I have edited my answer.
I agree that this is still kind of a work around, do you know if there is a better way of solving this problem?